# SharePoint 2013 Support?

Tags: external-integrations

Does anyone know if the Connector for SharePoint supports SharePoint version 2013? Has anyone been using this configuration? Has it worked well?

Answer (score 6):

If you are using Tridion 2013, see the Tridion documentation below on the SDL Tridion Connector 1.0 for the CMIS standard which should work with SharePoint 2013.

> Microsoft SharePoint 2013— CMIS is available on any on-premises SharePoint 2013 site after the Content Management Interoperability Services (CMIS) Producer feature is activated in the Manage Site Features section of Site Settings.

The connector is based on Tridion 2013 ECL (External Content Library) technology, which allows you to connect third party systems to the Tridion Content Management System.

**Documentation**

http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDLTridion_ECL_CMIS_10&lang=en-US

**CMIS Standard Intro**

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Management_Interoperability_Services

Answer (score 5):

The current version `SDL Tridion Connector 2011 for SharePoint` just supports SharePoint 2010. It means that is hasn't been tested with SharePoint 2013 and probably it won't work or the behavior will be unexpected.